# Bundling .NET Framework with Winforms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms app that is deployed using ClickOnce deployment. I'm using another Winforms project to customize the installation steps. So I would have to distribute the executable (of the installer project). Is there anyway to bundle the .NET framework 4.0 with the executable (either standalone or web installer) or should it be downloaded and installed separately?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, part of the ClickOnce deployment is the installation of the .NET framework (it can be found in the dependencies form). Why not use that and run the "customization" application afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

[dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/) is a "bootstrap" that can install dependencies, including the .NET framework, before launching the target application/installer.

> *dotNetInstaller enables the developer to define the application prerequisites and install the correct version(s) of these components* in a predictable order based on the processor architecture, user operating system type and language, allow the user to download these components from the web, install these components directly from a single packaged setup, local media or both ..
>
> A boostrapper doesn't replace tools like InstallShield, Wise, Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Project or Wix. *The goal is to create an application to help users with installing the correct prerequisites ..*